# Пользовательские скрипты для SO

Tags: предложение

Предлагаю размещать здесь апплеты/скрипты/букмарклеты, с помощью которых можно улучшить, либо персонализировать, взаимодействие с сайтом.

> *На данный момент в интерфейсе имеется инструмент пользовательских фильтров, но на момент написания поста они ещё не были реализованы. [Здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11459) идёт обсуждение некоторых особенностей этого инструмента.*

---

#### Пользовательский скрипт stackoverflow.user.js

[image: GitHub_badge]
[image: Version_badge]
[image: OpenUserJS_badge]
[image: GreasyFork badge]

Я использую расширение для [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net), но должно работать со всеми, которые поддерживают пользовательские скрипты.
Что реализовано на данный момент:

- добавлена возможность конфигурации скрипта;
  *(перевод и остальные настройки будут добавлены позже)*
  [image: Диалог настроек скрипта]
- добавлена возможность выбора языка
  *(пока используется только при перенаправлении поискового запроса на англоязычный сайт и обратно на локальный: ru, es, pt, ja)*;
- добавлена возможность добавления ссылки на Мета в боковое меню
  *(отключается в настройках)*;
  [image: Ссылки на Meta и на диалог настроек скрипта]
- в конце поля поиска добавлена кнопка для перехода на англоязычную версию сайта с текущим запросом
  *(отключается в настройках)*;
  [image: Кнопка для перенеаправления на англоязычную версию сайта]
- в блоке "Отслеживаемые метки" надпись является ссылкой для перехода ко всем вопросам с отслеживаемыми метками;
  [image: Кнопка для перехода ко всем вопросам с отслеживаемыми метками]
- блок "Важное на мете/Обсуждаемое на мете" можно сворачивать с сохранением состояния
  *(отключается в настройках)*;
  [image: Скрытие блока Мета]
- код из блоков и виджета кода можно копировать в буфер обмена;
  [image: Копирование кода из блоков и виджета]
- к карточке пользователя добавлены ссылки на его все вопросы и на вопросы с текущими метками вопроса;
  [image: Все вопросы пользователя]
  [image: Вопросы пользователя только с текущими метками]
- добавлена кнопка для растягивания и восстановления содержимого сайта (иногда полезно для удобного чтения кода с длинными строками кода);
  [image: Кнопка для растягивания содержимого страницы]
  [image: Кнопка для восстановления ширины содержимого страницы]

---

Букмарклет для перехода на страницу вопросов по всем отслеживаемым меткам

> *Блок "Отслеживаемые метки/Watched Tags" должен присутствовать на странице во время выполнения*

```js
var tags = [],
    urlPrefix = window.location.origin + "/questions/tagged/";

$(".js-watched-tag-list a.user-tag").each(function (idx, itm) {
    var url = itm.href;
    tags.push(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));
});
if (tags.length) {
    window.location.href = urlPrefix + tags.join("+or+");
} else {
    window.alert("Метки не найдены");
}

// Compressed
var a=[],b=window.location.origin+"/questions/tagged/";$(".js-watched-tag-list a.user-tag").each(function(e,d){var c=d.href;a.push(c.substring(c.lastIndexOf("/")+1))});a.length?window.location.href=b+a.join("+or+"):window.alert("\u041c\u0435\u0442\u043a\u0438 \u043d\u0435 \u043d\u0430\u0439\u0434\u0435\u043d\u044b");

// Encoded
javascript:(function()%7Bvar%20a%3D%5B%5D%2Cb%3Dwindow.location.origin%2B%22%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2F%22%3B%24(%22.js-watched-tag-list%20a.user-tag%22).each(function(e%2Cd)%7Bvar%20c%3Dd.href%3Ba.push(c.substring(c.lastIndexOf(%22%2F%22)%2B1))%7D)%3Ba.length%3Fwindow.location.href%3Db%2Ba.join(%22%2Bor%2B%22)%3Awindow.alert(%22%5Cu041c%5Cu0435%5Cu0442%5Cu043a%5Cu0438%20%5Cu043d%5Cu0435%20%5Cu043d%5Cu0430%5Cu0439%5Cu0434%5Cu0435%5Cu043d%5Cu044b%22)%7D)()
```

#### Как добавить букмарклет

Обычно букмарклеты публикуются как обычные ссылки, которые можно добавить в избранное обычным перетаскиванием. Атрибут ссылки href содержит кодированный скрипт, который будет выполнен на текущей странице. Из-за того, что скрипт выполняется в текущей странице, это несёт потенциальную угрозу безопасности и скорее всего по этой причине SO не поддерживает ссылки начинающиеся с javascript.
Ниже показано как добавить букмарклет на примере браузера Google Chrome.

[image: Как добавить букмарклет в Google Chrome]

#### Расширения для пользовательских скриптов

На данный момент популярны три расширения для браузеров, это:

1. [image] Tampermonkey для [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/tampermonkey/), [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/extensions/details/tampermonkey-beta/) и [Safari](https://www.tampermonkey.net/?browser=safari).
2. [image] Violentmonkey для [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/violent-monkey/jinjaccalgkegednnccohejagnlnfdag), [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/violentmonkey/) и [Opera](https://violentmonkey.github.io/get-it/)
3. [image] Greasemonkey только для [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)

#### Ссылки по теме

- [Google Closure Compiler](https://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/)
- [Bookmarklet Creator](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82)
- [Букмарклет Wikipedia](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/ispolzujte-bukmarklety-dlya-bystrogo-vypolneniya-z)
- [Mozilla о букмарклетах](https://support.mozilla.org/ru/kb/ispolzujte-bukmarklety-dlya-bystrogo-vypolneniya-z)

Comment: Что с этим букмарклетом делать? Почему не в виде скрипта для Tampermonkey?

Comment: @АндрейNOP делать с ним все то же самое, что и с любым букмарклутом: добавлять в закладки

Comment: @edem предлагайте свои варианты, т.к. критика должна быть конструктивной.

Comment: Добавил. Проверяйте.

Comment: @edem не оценил Ваших саркастических правок.

Comment: Если англичанину нужно новое слово, то он его придумывает. Если русскому (не каждому) нужно новое слово, то он идёт к англичанину. Не устали?

Comment: @edem не понимаю, каким образом это относится к теме? Существуют де-факто устоявшиеся термины с сфере IT, которые понимают и принимают большинство в сообществе. И если уж на то пошло, то не "закладник", а закладка, не "обзорщик", а интернет обозреватель... На мой это не лучшее место для подобных дискуссий.

Comment: @XelaNimed о чём и речь, англоязычное меньшинство придумывает, не парясь (зайдите на английские страничники StackExchange), а потом русское большинство в том числе это "принимает". Закладка, это закладка, а здесь упор на исполняемоемость оной, новое понятие. Дискуссий... Обсуждений тогда уж.

Comment: Не знаю, как остальных, но меня этот вопрос оттолкнул с первого слова в названии. Гугл транслейт вовсе считает его [сербским](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tODsp.png).

Comment: @αλεχολυτ изменил. Самому глаз резало :)

Answer (score 7):

Украл идею у [@tym32167](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8355/#12155), но я использовал чистый JavaScript, плюс сделал разделение под вопросы / ответы. (Подробности использования и т.п. ниже кода)

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name Comments Templates (Stack Overflow)
// @description готовые комментарии под сообщения низкого качества, потому что з*****о.
// @version 1.0.0
// @license GPL-3.0-or-later
// @author NNL993
// @namespace -
// @match *://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/*/*
// @match *://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/*
// @grant none
// @run-at document-start
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    const HOTKEY_CODE = 'Tab'
    const QUOTE = {
        LEFT: '«',
        RIGHT: '»',
    }
    const ACTIVE_COLOR = 'var(--theme-primary-color-legacy)'

    const QUESTION_CAN_EDIT = ` Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой ${QUOTE.LEFT}[edit]${QUOTE.RIGHT}.`
    const ANSWER_CAN_EDIT = ` Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой ${QUOTE.LEFT}%EDIT${QUOTE.RIGHT}.`
    const WELCOME = `Добро пожаловать на ${QUOTE.LEFT}StackOverflow на русском${QUOTE.RIGHT}! `

    const comments = {
        question: [
            'В этом сообществе все вопросы / ответы / комментарии обязательно должны быть **на русском** языке, исправьте своё сообщение заменив текст на русский.' + QUESTION_CAN_EDIT,
            'Название вопроса должно исключительно включать тему проблемы или текст ошибки, а уже сами подробности должны быть **в вопросе**.' + QUESTION_CAN_EDIT,
            'Вопрос задан не по теме сообщества StackOverflow. Вы можете подробнее ознакомится с темами на которые можно задавать вопросы [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).',
            'Вопросы должны также содержать попытки автора решить задачу, без них (попыток), вопрос будет являться учебным заданием. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error).',
            'Ответы на данный вопрос скорее всего будут основаны на личном, *субъективном* опыте, стоит исправить вопрос так, чтобы ответы на него были исключительно *объективные*. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).' + QUESTION_CAN_EDIT,
            '[Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/12119/#12120).',
            '[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).',
            '**Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).'
        ],
        answer: [
            'Пожалуйста, постарайтесь давать более развёрнутые ответы, ответ на вопрос должен быть **исчерпывающим**. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).' + ANSWER_CAN_EDIT,
            'Ссылаться на внешний материал конечно хорошо, но также нужно оставлять цитаты (и код если имеется) из ссылок, чтобы пользователи понимали что из ждёт из ссылки, а также это будет полезно если доступ к ресурсу был потерян. Подробнее [в справке](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).',
            'В этом сообществе все вопросы / ответы / комментарии обязаны быть **на русском** языке, исправьте своё сообщение заменив текст на русский.' + ANSWER_CAN_EDIT,
        ]
    }

    let currentComments = 'question'
    const TEXTAREA_SELECTOR = '.comment-form textarea'
    const _HOTKEY_CODE = getHotkeyCode()

    window.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
        if(e.code === _HOTKEY_CODE) {
            e.preventDefault()

            const textarea = e.target
            const parent = textarea.parentNode

            if(textarea.matches(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR)) {
                const contentArea = textarea.closest('.answer, .question')
                const isAnswer = contentArea.classList.contains('answer')
                const isNewContributor = Boolean(contentArea.querySelector('.new-contributor-indicator'))
                const select = document.createElement('div')
                const id = contentArea.getAttribute('data-questionid') || contentArea.getAttribute('data-answerid')

                currentComments = isAnswer ? 'answer' : 'question'

                select.className = 'ils-comment-hints'

                correctProps()

                select.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(255, 255, 255)'
                select.style.color = 'rgb(0, 0 ,0)'
                select.style.position = 'absolute'
                select.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
                select.style.zIndex = 10

                select.innerHTML = comments[currentComments].map(el => {
                    const textContent = el
                      .replace('%EDIT', '[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/%ID/edit)')
                      .replace('%ID', id)

                    return `<div style="padding: 1em;" class="ils-comment-hints-item" data-text="${(isNewContributor ? WELCOME : '') + textContent}">${textContent}</div>`
                }).join('')

                if(parent.querySelector('.ils-comment-hints') === null) {
                    parent.appendChild(select)

                    window.addEventListener('resize', correctProps)
                }

                window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

                function correctProps() {
                    if(!textarea) {
                        return window.removeEventListener('resize', correctProps)
                    }

                    select.style.top = textarea.offsetTop + textarea.offsetHeight + 'px'
                    select.style.left = textarea.offsetLeft + 'px'
                    select.style.width = textarea.offsetWidth + 'px'
                }
            }
        }
    })

    let currentIndex = 0

    window.addEventListener('keyup', e => {
        if(e.code === _HOTKEY_CODE) {
            document.querySelectorAll('.ils-comment-hints').forEach(e => {
                e.remove()
            })

            window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown)

            currentIndex = 0
        }
    })


    function onKeyDown(e) {
        const commentsLength = comments[currentComments].length

        switch (e.code) {
            case 'ArrowDown':
                currentIndex += 1

                if(currentIndex > commentsLength) {
                    currentIndex = 1
                }
                break
            case 'ArrowUp':
                currentIndex += -1

                if(currentIndex < 1) {
                    currentIndex = commentsLength
                }
                break
            default:
                return
        }

        currentIndex = Math.max(1, Math.min(commentsLength, currentIndex)) // MIN - 1; MAX - commentsLength

        const target = e.target

        if(target.matches(TEXTAREA_SELECTOR)) {
            chooseActive(currentIndex)

            function chooseActive(index) {
                unmakeActive(document.querySelector('.ils-comment-hints-item.active'))

                makeActive(document.querySelector(`.ils-comment-hints-item:nth-of-type(${index})`))
            }

            function unmakeActive(el) {
                if(el) {
                    el.classList.remove('active')
                    el.style.backgroundColor = ''
                }
            }

            function makeActive(el) {
                if(el) {
                    el.classList.add('active')
                    el.style.backgroundColor = ACTIVE_COLOR
                    target.value = el.dataset.text
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getHotkeyCode() {
        return typeof HOTKEY_CODE === 'string' ? HOTKEY_CODE.trim() : 'Tab'
    }
})()
```

#### Использование

- Переходим на страницу вопроса / какой-то очереди проверки
- Нажимаем "Добавить комментарий"
- Зажимаем <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Profit. (Стрелками <kbd>↑</kbd> / <kbd>↓</kbd> можно управлять)

#### Нюансы

- Если участник новый, то тогда к надписи добавляется текст из переменной `WELCOME`.
- Если вы налажали с синтаксисом или по какой-то причине переменная `HOTKEY_CODE` отсутствует, то тогда горячей клавишей будет <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

#### Редактирование

`HOTKEY_CODE` - это та горячая клавиша, на которую будет открываться список (по стандарту `Tab`), для того чтобы, например открывать список на `M`, нужно написать `KeyM`, если допустим `F1`, тогда и пишем `F1`.

*Как получить код клавиши, на которую хочешь назначить открытие?* Откройте консоль разработчика нажатием клавиши <kbd>F12</kbd> или комбинацией клавиш <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>, далее зайдите во вкладку **Console**, и там вставьте этот код в поле ввода:  `addEventListener('keydown', e => console.log(e.code), {once: true})`, далее нажмите <kbd>Enter</kbd>, чтобы запустить код. Нажмите на страницу, чтобы сфокусироваться на ней и нажмите на ту клавишу, которую вы хотите использовать для открытия меню. После нажатия в консоли должна появиться строка с кодом клавиши, эту строку и вставьте в переменную `HOTKEY_CODE`.

`QUOTE` - это кавычки, которые будут использоваться в тексте, если хотите, можете их изменить, `LEFT` - кавычка слева, `RIGHT` - кавычка справа.

`ACTIVE_COLOR` - цвет, которым будет подсвечиваться текущий выбранный текст, по стандарту, этот цвет - цвет темы веб-сайта.

#### Комментарии

Есть два массива в переменной `comments`, первый `question`, где хранятся комментарии под вопросы и второй `answer`, где хранятся комментарии под ответы, в строках можно использовать весь Markdown который поддерживается для комментариев. Также в строках заменяются некоторые значения, вот они:

- `%ID` - текущий ID поста (ответа / вопроса). Пример: `Это пост %ID!` -> `Это пост 8355!`.
- `%EDIT` - равносильно записи `[edit]`, но есть поддержка для ответов (Я не был уверен работает ли `[edit]` на ответы, так что на всякий случай сделал такой вариантик). Пример: `Отредактируйте своё сообщение кнопкой %EDIT, пожалуйста!` -> `Отредактируйте своё сообщение кнопкой [править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/%ID/edit), пожалуйста!`. (`%ID` позже заменяется на текущий ID поста)

Есть также заготовленные переменные, чтобы не печатать одно и тоже много раз (предполагается что вы будете их использовать в конце сообщения):

- `QUESTION_CAN_EDIT` - равен этой записи:  `Вопрос можно отредактировать кнопкой «[edit]».`
- `ANSWER_CAN_EDIT` - равен этой записи:  `Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «%EDIT»`

Пример использования:

`'Любое сообщение должно быть **на русском** языке!' + QUESTION_CAN_EDIT`

#### Скриншот

[image: пример]

Comment: Отлично! Был бы очень рад такому функционалу.

Comment: @Павел Мне самому также удобно, надоело каждый раз писать одни и те же слова :)

Comment: Я слишком ленив, потому у меня есть блокнот, где есть все нужные мне тексты :)

Answer (score 4):

Мне однажды надоело одно и то же печатать в комментариях под вопросами низкого качества, потому я накатал простой скрипт для шаблонов комментов. Никогда подобного не делал, так что супер качества не стоит ожидать. У скрипта есть зависимось - JQuery UI (я настолько стар, да)

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       tym32167
// @match        *://ru.stackoverflow.com/*
// @require      https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/jquery-ui.min.js
// @resource     IMPORTED_CSS https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.13.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css
// @grant        GM_getResourceText
// @grant        GM_addStyle

// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    const my_css = GM_getResourceText("IMPORTED_CSS");
    GM_addStyle(my_css);

    var availableTags = [
        {label: "В вашем вопросе отсутвует вопрос.", value:"В вашем вопросе отсутвует вопрос."},
        {label: "Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки. ", value:"Ваш вопрос низкого качества. Ознакомьтесь с информацией из справки [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"},
        {label: "На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?", value:"[На какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)"},
        {label: "Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?", value:"[Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в коде на C#?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/701429/179763)"},
    ];

    $(".question-page").on("focus", "[name='comment']", function (event) {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags,
            minLength:0
        });
        $(this).autocomplete('search', $(this).val())
    });
})();
```

Работает так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Привет Тим! Хорошая идея! Нужно будет добавить такую "фичу" в ruSO скрипт : )

Comment: @XelaNimed да, было бы неплохо. Мне по сути только автокомплит и нужен был, я больше ничем нестандартным и не пользуюсь.

Answer (score 3):

> На данный момент в интерфейсе SO не предусмотрено удобное отслеживание
>   вопросов по всем отслеживаемым меткам. Никто конечно не запрещает
>   вручную добавлять метки, либо сохранять ссылку на ранее созданный
>   запрос.

Сейчас не так. Теперь можно воспользоваться "Пользовательскими фильтрами" для удобного отслеживания вопросов по заданным меткам. Необходимости в закладниках (bookmarklet) больше нет.

[Пример использования](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/9646/199733).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это сейчас. Думаете подправить нужно?

Comment: @XelaNimed можете про них упомянуть просто.