# Делимся советами как искать полезные вопросы

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы

Предлагаю поделиться наработками и способами от опытных пользователей, как они находят для себя полезные и увлекательные вопросы среди множества разнообразных направлений, разбросанных по разным меткам данной площадки.

Comment: Я просто читаю подряд все заголовки на главной странице. Если что-то вызывает интерес, захожу и читаю текст вопроса.

Comment: Я просто смотрю интересующие меня метки - c#, javascript (на заглавной слишком много мимо)

Comment: Смотрю по меткам, очень редко по заголовкам. На `Mete` только по заголовкам)

Answer (score 10):

Самый простой и привычный способ поиска это *просмотр главной страницы* и *просмотр по меткам*, но **выхлоп** от него, как правило, **небольшой** из-за *большого количества мусора* (на главной странице) и *значительных временных трат* на переключение между несколькими отслеживаемыми метками.

Моё решение:

1. Создаём Пользовательские фильтры, в которых объединены по смыслу различные метки:

   - HTML, CSS: html or html5 or css or css3 or html5 ...
   - JavaScript: javascript or jquery or react ...
   - Базы данных: mysql or postgresql or sql or sqlite ...

   ...

   В качестве первоначальных меток для наполнения фильтров можно выбрать существующие отслеживаемые.

   Пример:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Все метки, которые используются в фильтрах, скрываем из отслеживания. Таким образом они не будут отображаться на главной странице, вместо них там будут появляться вопросы из областей, которые пока ещё не попали в какой-либо фильтр.
3. Повторяем шаги 1-2 для меток, которые будут появляться на главной странице.
4. Смотрим наличие уведомления рядом с фильтром (красный кружок слева) о том, что по такой-то метке для какого-либо фильтра появились новые вопросы.
5. Переходим по фильтрам, которые обозначены красным.
6. Просматриваем список новых вопросов (они тоже будут отображены красным кружком).
7. Отвечаем на понравившийся и/или переходим к шагу 5.
8. Не забываем про личную жизнь.

Comment: Warning: Шаг 8 unreachable code detected.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko скорее, `NullPointerException` (:

Answer (score 3):

Просматривать главную страницу, с целью нахождения интересных вопросов, действительно нет большого смысла. Она скорее служит индикатором активности в данный временной промежуток. 
Каждый, кто много отвечает, как правило имеет свой набор меток. И вот внутри этих меток можно идти по двум направлениям:

**1. Лучшие авторы вопросов с меткой ...**

*Первичный уровень выявления авторов интересных вопросов.*
Если человек много спрашивает и при этом имеет большое положительное сальдо, то стоит присмотреться к его вопросам. Если действительно они интересны, то видимо нужно запомнить его ник и не пропускать его вопросов. Достаточно 5-10 авторов по одной метке, чтобы иметь кейс для ответов.
К сожалению тут нет постоянства. Человек год, два задаёт интересные вопросы, потом исчезает из армии вопрошающих.

Часто бывает, что очень слабый вопрос получает много плюсов из-за наличия отличных ответов. Но это другая история.

**2. Лучшие авторы ответов с меткой ...**

Почему нужно смотреть авторов лучших ответов для поиска интересных вопросов?

Ответ прост, - они сделали тему интересной своими ответами. Топик, как правило, имеет большое количеством просмотров, с большой долей вероятности, что они будут расти и можно разместить рядом свой вариант ответа.
Или вопрос действительно актуален и интересен.

3. **При полном штиле наличия интересных вопросов** можно спросить себя и ответить самому себе. При этом в процессе написания ответа идёт более глубокое погружение в тему. Есть и игровой плюс само ответов - Золотая медалька - **Сократ**, за сто разных дней с положительным балансом.

**Update**

4. Немного не по теме Хотя... с целью набрать кейс добротных вопросов можно действовать и с канцелярским подходом:

При просмотре  видишь стоящий, интересный вопрос и уже в голове складываются идеи ответа, но вот прямо сейчас нет времени или желания отвечать. Тогда складываешь файлик с заголовком и ссылкой на топик в отдельную папку. Потом, когда появится возможность ответить или при полном штиле, выбираешь из этой папки отложенный вопрос и отвечаешь. 
Я пришёл к такому канцелярскому способу не сразу, а после многих неудачных попыток найти нужный вопрос, который точно видел, но поиском так и не смог найти.