# Добавление способа логического объединения тегов в пользовательском фильтре

Tags: предложение, метки, интерфейс

Всё время пользовался своим пользовательским скриптом для добавления небольших плюшек о котором писал [здесь](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8355). Сегодня наконец-то попробовал пользовательский фильтр и был немного опечален отсутствием настройки логического объединения меток (`and` или `or`). Насколько я понимаю, сейчас выбранные метки объединяются с логическим "и", т.е. это означает, что вопрос должен соответствовать всем выбранным меткам.
Но есть небольшая проблема: если посмотреть на все метки связанные с JavaScript или какой-либо другой популярной тематикой, то становится понятно, что меток очень и очень много и если создавать фильтры так как они есть сейчас, то придётся по сути повторять метки с небольшими различиями. Отсюда возникает вопрос: планируется ли добавить к пользовательскому фильтру возможность указания способа логического объединения меток? Если нет и не планируется, то можно ли что-то предпринять, чтоб это было запланировано?

Answer (score 1):

Сайт умеет искать метки через or: [`user:178988 is:q [javascript] or [c#]`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A178988+is%3Aq+%5Bjavascript%5D+or+%5Bc%23%5D).

Comment: Я знаю и активно пользуюсь объединением меток так [c#] or [.net] or [.net-core], но вопрос в том, будет ли это реализовано в нативном интерфейсе, чтоб не приходилось подтанцовывать с бубном.