# Не хватает пробела в сообщении о превышении лимита символов в поле "О себе"

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, профиль-участника, ограничения

Собственно, на картинке всё видно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да вообще убрать этот лимит. Хочу шаблонные комментарии в профиле писать)

Comment: @Зонтик, я на этот баг и наткнулся когда хотел добавить очередной шаблон. Больше уже нельзя (

Comment: `Хочу шаблонные комментарии` -- Можно использовать [пользовательский скрипт](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/12309/474588)

Comment: @ΝNL993, классный скрипт, спасибо за ссылку )

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предложил другой [вариант](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/5640) "перевода":

Было:

> В тексте «О себе» разрешено $numChars$ символов; вы ввели$entered$

Стало:

> В тексте «О себе» разрешено $numChars$ символов; вы ввели $entered$

Comment: Перевод утвердил. Но из-за существующего [бага](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395096/339911) он вряд ли появится в следующей сборке. Текущая 2024.1.10.3270.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, проверил - работает! повесьте [tag:статус-завершено].

Comment: Интересно, возможно проблема с переводом касается только новых исходных строк, а старые можно обновить.